# JQuery UI datepicker: how to bind an event AFTER the calendar was rendered?

Tags: jquery, events, jquery-ui, datepicker, primefaces

I am using [datepicker](http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/). The usual way to bind an event, lets say for example, `beforeShowDay`, would be:

```
$('.selector').datepicker({
   beforeShowDay: function(date) { ... }
});
```

What I need is to bind the `beforeShowDay` event after the calendar was rendered. So, let's say first I render the calendar:

```
$('.mySpecialContainer').datepicker({
   //in this moment, for some reason, I am not allowed to bind nothing (that's not me who renders the calendar, that's why I am not allowed)
});
```

And then, if I try to bind something in the usual way:

```
$('.mySpecialContainer').datepicker({
   beforeShowDay: function(date) { ... }
});
```

The calendar will be - of course - rendered again inside `'.mySpecialContainer'`, instead of just binding the event. I have tried:

```
$('.mySpecialContainer').bind('beforeShowDay', function(date) { ... });
```

But that was just a desperate action :)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It doesn't make sense to me why you can't call `bind` on that particular `datepicker` event (or, for that matter, most `datepicker` events). Most other jQueryUI widgets allow late-binding of events.

However, you can try the following. `hasDatepicker` is applied to datepickers, and calling `.datepicker` again on those elements is *not* reinitializing the widget, it's just modifying an option:

```
$('.hasDatepicker').datepicker("option", "beforeShowDay", 
    function(date) { ... });
```

Comment: this is just the same as `$('.mySpecialContainer').datepicker({
   beforeShowDay: function(date) { ... }
});` this won't work for me, because the calendar is already rendered. is there a formal way I can get the DatePicker object? I'm trying `$('.hasDatepicker')` but this just a selector that brings me a container, nothing but that

Comment: @bluefoot: I thought you had a selector which contained elements with datepicker widgets attached? Are you saying you need to find elements with `datepicker`s attached and *then* attach the event?

Comment: @bluefoot: I think I see what you mean. `$(".hasDatepicker")` does return the element(s) that `datepicker()` was initially called on, but you can modify options by using the `.datepicker("option", ...)` function, see my updated answer. I can provide an example if necessary.

Comment: just the same again. my container is a `<div id="whatever" />` if I do `$('#whatever').datepicker()`, it creates a inner element with (amont other things) the class `hasDatepicker`. I've already tried your second example before. we are trying to discover this on prime faces forum too: http://primefaces.prime.com.tr/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=8224&p=32586#p32585

Comment: Maybe this is purely a primefaces issue? I've never worked with it before. However, you should definitely be able to grab a jQuery widget instance and modify it.

Comment: I am not talking about primefaces anymore. I am trying in a pure html file. it has only a div with id `datepicker`. and a script `$( "#datepicker" ).datepicker();`, to create the datepicker. when I execute your `$('.hasDatepicker').datepicker("option", "beforeShowDay", 
     function(date) { alert('whatever') });` it just destroys the rendered datepicker. it appears that biding events to a datepicker only works in the creation time...

Comment: @bluefoot: You must return the expected array from the event handler. Check out this example: http://jsfiddle.net/andrewwhitaker/yrv5t/2/ What's different about what you're trying to do?

Answer (score 1):

```
$('.ui-datepicker-current-day').click();
```

Answer (score 0):

Using jQuery UI 1.13.1, I have used the `onUpdateDatepicker` to bind a mouseover event on the calendar, and I was able to create a hover even for each of the days in the calendar. For example:

```js
// JS for datepicker
  $("#myDatepicker").datepicker({
      showOptions: { direction: "down" },
      
      // bind mouseover event for the calendar
      onUpdateDatepicker: function () {
          const tbody = $('.ui-datepicker-calendar > tbody')
          tbody.mouseover(function(e) {
              const target = $(e.target);
              
              // only fire hover when target has no children (is <a>)
              if (target.has('a').length == 0) {
                $('#results > span').html(target.html());
              }
          })
      }
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.13.1/jquery-ui.min.js" /></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.13.1/themes/start/jquery-ui.css" />

<div style="display: flex; flex-direction: row; justify-content: center; justify-items: cetner; gap: 25px;">
  <input type="text" id='myDatepicker' placeholder="click 4 date hover" />
  <div id="results">Hovering over day <span style="color: red;">none</span>.</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -2):

You need `.live()`. 
http://api.jquery.com/live/

```
$('.mySpecialContainer').live('beforeShowDay', function(date) { ... });
```

On second thought, I think I misunderstood the question... You need to have a datepicker without a function, and then later on give it a function? You'll probably be best off removing the datepicker and putting it back on.

Comment: Yes. The datepicker is created by JSF Primefaces and it's bound to a ManagedBean field. So I don't want to mess up with it. I just want to bind the event after the component is rendered with Primefaces. So, removing the datepicker and putting it back on: no way :)